# Basic cookie registration script

Tags: php, javascript, html, cookies, registration

I've been trying to create a form that generates a cookie that contains a username, password, email address and a DOB. Then after they succcessfully complete the form and submit it, it should re-direct them. I also need a privacy policy that allows them to accept the cookie or reject it and re-directed to say Google.

I wouldn't mind links to guides to work it out myself, but I'd love for someone to help me out with writing this and explaining it. ^_^ I've tried using w3schools and the information my teacher gave me, but I can't get it to all work properly only bits and parts.

EDIT:

I've been messing around, just trying to generate a cookie and etc.

What I've got so far:

**Registration.html**

```
<SCRIPT src="../js/cookie.js"></SCRIPT>

<FORM NAME="cf">

<b>Enter A Word:</b> <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="cfd" size="20"><P>

<CENTER><INPUT TYPE="button" Value="Set to Cookie" onClick="putCookie()"></CENTER>

</FORM>
```

**cookie.js**

```
cookie_name = "dataCookie";

var YouEntered;



function putCookie() {



 if(document.cookie != document.cookie) 

    {index = document.cookie.indexOf(cookie_name);}

 else 

    { index = -1;}



 if (index == -1)

  {

  Username=document.cf.cfd.value;
  Password=document.cf.password.value;
  Email=document.cf.email.value;
  DOB=document.cf.DOB.value;

  document.cookie=cookie_name+"="+Username+"+Password+"+Email+"+DOB+"; expires=Monday, 06-Apr-2020 05:00:00 GMT";

  }



}
```

It's a half done script, I'm just messing around with it at the moment. I'm aware that the document.cookie is a mess and that I'm missing my forms for the everything expect username. But you asked for me to post what I've got so far, as you can see it's not much.

Comment: Since you have already tried something, post what you have so far and explain what is not working properly.

Comment: I've deleted my failed scripts, sorry. It's why I've came here, because  I'm at a lost how to do it.